# How to remove node from array using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove userid 2 from the following array using javascript

```
{"maxPages":2,"data":[{"UserId":"1","UserName":peterparker,"}{"UserId":"2","UserName":spiderman,"}]}
```

I was thinking of first getting the index like:
      id = 2
      row = myarray.data.UserId.indexOf(id)

Then remove the row based on the index

Comment: [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Always use `delete` on array elements. Besides, is there not multiple syntax errors with this declaration?

Comment: @MartinAndersson delete does not change array length by shifting elements to fill the space

Comment: @MartinAndersson Never use `delete` with arrays. Use `delete` with objects, and use `splice()` with arrays (or generate a new array).

Comment: If you don't care about the sort order, then just iterate the Array, and when you find the one you're looking for, relocate the last item in the Array to that index, and then reduce the `.length` by `1`.

Comment: sorry, wasn't clear in my comment. I know `delete` won't change length. I always like to **use** `delete` though before doing anything else. If I remember it correctly, that was the only way for me to make sure the garbage collector eventually kicked in. But I might probably not remember it correctly since it was a long time ago I really programmed in JavaScript. Anyone got an update on that one?

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {}; // ...your object

for ( var i = 0; i < obj.data.length ) {
    if ( obj.data[i].UserId == 2 ) {
        obj.data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `obj.data[i].UserId == 2` not `obj.data[i].UserId = 2`

Comment: @MoazzamKhan - Yuck! Maybe I should switch to Yoda notation :)

Comment: Yoda notation is so ugly :D

Comment: @MoazzamKhan - It sure is, but it'll prevent errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilies:

1. [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), but you need to know index of corresponding entry.
2. [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which is slightly less efficient, but more convinient:

   ```
   var obj = {"maxPages":2,"data":[{"UserId":"1","UserName":peterparker,"}{"UserId":"2","UserName":spiderman,"}]};
   obj.data = obj.data.filter(function(v) { return v.UserId != 2 });
   ```

Comment: How is `.filter()` less efficient?

Comment: I suppose it'd act pretty straightforward, like: create a new array, push required items, return this new array, delete old one. Whereas `splice` would need only to remove one element and shift remaining, which can be done without mem. allocations.

Comment: While you may think that, `splice` is slow compared to other methods: http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter

Comment: For me (Chrome 28.0.1500.95 on Linux 64-bit) `splice` performs a bit faster than built-in filter, thought hand-written filter (named push in testcase) is 4 times faster. Also I'm not sure about various compiler optimizations in this syntetic test case.

Answer (score 0):

The one of joellustigman works for me, but it has two little grammar corrections, the i++ and the "==" instead of "="

```
var obj = {
"maxPages":2,
"data":[{
"UserId":"1",
"UserName":"peterparker"
},
{"UserId":"2",
"UserName":"spiderman"
}
]}

for ( var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++ ) {
    if ( obj.data[i].UserId == "2" ) {
        obj.data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
myarray.data = myarray.data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.UserId !== 2;
});
```